# what is the difference between request and session scope in spring?

Tags: spring, session, dependency-injection, request, autowired

In request scope, a bean is defined to an HTTP request whereas in session scope, it is scoped to an HTTP session.
So for an instance,

if the bean scope is **request** and, a user makes more than one request for a web page in his user session, then on every request a new bean would be created.

Whereas if the scope is defined as **session** for the bean, if a user makes a request for a web page more than once, then on every request same bean would be returned.

please let me know if this understanding is correct?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. However I would like to add something

> Whereas if the scope is defined as session for the bean, if a user
> makes a request for a web page more than once, then on every request
> same bean would be returned.

I would change it as "Whereas if the scope is defined as session for the bean, if a user makes a request for a web page more than once, then on every request same bean would be returned, **as long as the requests are within the same user session and made from a client which is capable of maintaining the session (You can't expect the `curl` to maintain the usersession unless you pass the cookie/session identifier header).**"

Comment: - by this mean if I am creating a REST based APIs and is not using any session variable - Session Scope and Request Scope becomes same??

Answer (score 10):

**Session Scope** -- when the scope is session,the values of formbean(form data) would be available throughout the session. it will not destroyed until session timeout up or session destroyed.

**Request Scope** -- when the scope is request,the values of formbean(form data) would be available for the current request. it will refresh on every request of same user/different user.

because http is stateless protocol

Comment: Does session here mean the browser session?

Comment: @Naman: It's about the server session, server session is stored in the browser, we set the session, update the session and destroyed the session using backend code.